# WPF scrolling marquee - HandOffBehavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend, doubleanimation

I am trying to figure out how to best use WPF's HandOffBehavior technique. Right now, I have a scrolling error marquee in my application that animates opening up, scrolling the error message, and then closing itself.

I was just starting to build this WPF application this week. The problem is that I can't seem to gracefully prepare for a scenario like when the user clicks the Login button twice or more times in small consecutive intervals. I would like to see the error marquee only continue sending the error text across the screen when the user commits such behavior with the login button rather than open and close the marquee multiple redundant times, etc. Here's the relevant code.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using PasswordHash;

namespace ChatClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void logIn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string nameRecord = "";
            string passRecord = "";

            if (UsernameField.Text == "" || UserPassField.Password == "")
            {
                openErrorMarquee("Username and password required");
            }
            else
            {
                using (otongadgethubEntities logCheck = new otongadgethubEntities())
                {
                    var userNullCheck = logCheck.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == UsernameField.Text);
                    if (userNullCheck == null)
                    {
                        openErrorMarquee("Username does not exist");
                    }

                    if (userNullCheck != null)
                    {
                        nameRecord = userNullCheck.username;
                    }

                    if (nameRecord == UsernameField.Text)
                    {
                        passRecord = Encrypt.MD5(UserPassField.Password).ToLower();
                        if (passRecord == userNullCheck.password)
                        {
                            //Yay! User logged in!
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            openErrorMarquee("Password invalid");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void openErrorMarquee(string errorMessage)
        {
            errorMarquee.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            DoubleAnimation openMarquee = new DoubleAnimation();
            openMarquee.From = 0;
            openMarquee.To = 17;
            openMarquee.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
            openMarquee.Completed += (s, doneEvent) => errorMarqueeScroll(errorMessage);
            errorMarquee.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, openMarquee, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
        }

        private void errorMarqueeScroll(string errorMessage)
        {
            errorText.Text = errorMessage;
            errorText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            double height = errorCanvas.ActualHeight - errorText.ActualHeight;
            errorText.Margin = new Thickness(0, height / 2, 0, 0);
            DoubleAnimation doubleErrorAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            doubleErrorAnimation.From = -errorText.ActualWidth;
            doubleErrorAnimation.To = errorCanvas.ActualWidth;

            //doubleErrorAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            doubleErrorAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(closeErrorMarquee);
            doubleErrorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7.0));
            errorText.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleErrorAnimation);
        }

        private void closeErrorMarquee(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation closeMarquee = new DoubleAnimation();
            closeMarquee.From = 17;
            closeMarquee.To = 0;
            closeMarquee.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
            closeMarquee.Completed += (s, doneEvent) => {
                errorMarquee.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                errorText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            };
            errorMarquee.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, closeMarquee, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML for those that need to see the window too:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="ChatClient.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="media/favicon.gif" Background="#FF3C3636" Foreground="{x:Null}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="logolayer2excompsoundfad_mp4"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6F6D95" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.BorderBrush>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource logolayer2excompsoundfad_mp4}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Menu" Fill="#755E5E83" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="273" Margin="35,23,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" RadiusY="27.5" RadiusX="27.5"/>
        <Button Content="Log In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="162,200,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource OTonButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#FF1C045B" Click="logIn"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="UsernameField" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="204,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="[Username]" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Background="#BD251E1E" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBox.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1E2E95" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.Foreground>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="98,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0A1D5F" Offset="0.374"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6E7FB9" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="UserPassField" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="204,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Background="#BD251E1E" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <PasswordBox.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1E2E95" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </PasswordBox.Foreground>
        </PasswordBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="98,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0A1D5F" Offset="0.374"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6E7FB9" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
        <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="errorCanvas" Width="446" Height="17" Margin="36,152,35,151">
            <Rectangle x:Name="errorMarquee" Fill="#FF0A0A0C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Stroke="#FF5B1D1D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" Canvas.Left="-1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="errorText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="690" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF7E0202" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Anyone have any suggestions, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use one flag to check this

```
private static flag = true;
private void logIn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(flag){
        flag=false;
        string nameRecord = "";
        string passRecord = "";

        if (UsernameField.Text == "" || UserPassField.Password == "")
        {
            openErrorMarquee("Username and password required");
        }
        else
        {
            using (otongadgethubEntities logCheck = new otongadgethubEntities())
            {
                var userNullCheck = logCheck.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == UsernameField.Text);
                if (userNullCheck == null)
                {
                    openErrorMarquee("Username does not exist");
                }

                if (userNullCheck != null)
                {
                    nameRecord = userNullCheck.username;
                }

                if (nameRecord == UsernameField.Text)
                {
                    passRecord = Encrypt.MD5(UserPassField.Password).ToLower();
                    if (passRecord == userNullCheck.password)
                    {
                        //Yay! User logged in!
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        openErrorMarquee("Password invalid");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
      else
      {
      openErrorMarquee("you pressed more one time");
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have to say though, due to the structure of the events (especially since when's called when another animation is completed, opening the marquee rectangle, closing it, etc.) that this does not sufficiently address the problem. It merely causes all the events to fire yet again and then the same problem will still persist- marquee closing earlier than it should, opening another time even though I only want it to "open" once to scroll error messages, etc. I'm trying to fix breaks in this UI.

Comment: Like if I hit the Log In button three times super fast, the whole errorMarquee animation behavior and its errorText will go haywire, with eventually the errorText hiding itself for a while, the marquee opening and opening, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StopWatch to check fast clicks. In code example given below, try pressing button slow and fast.

```
    Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
    long milliseconds_prev = 0;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_checkFastClicks())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fast click");
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("Slow click");
    }

    bool _checkFastClicks()
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (!w.IsRunning)
        {
            w.Start();
        }
        if (w.IsRunning)
        {
            if (w.ElapsedMilliseconds - milliseconds_prev < 500)//imp
            {
                if (w.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0)
                {
                    milliseconds_prev = w.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                    result = false;
            }
            else
            {
                milliseconds_prev = 0;
                w.Reset();
                w.Stop();
                result = false;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll have to try that later, maybe when we get to the Denver airport. Thanks! I'll let you know if I find something out